# Convert ECDSA private hex key to public key

Tags: openssl, hex, ecdsa

I'm using the below two lines to generate a hex of an ECDSA private key:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -out data.pem

openssl ec -in data.pem -outform DER|tail -c +8|head -c 32|xxd -p -c 32
```

Those output something like this:

```
059f2c8f5b1978bcc02d4b41e75c3aae99f3194fb06b53ffd256178e1367a2a6
```

How can I then use that hex key to generate a public ECDSA key, something like this?

```
043d6fa62769c10ceb28d3c13ae1e2329888e99d9c8bf854cc5bdcea0b7cd3002a0f5d244e35eec297c8eb4098b75295328cdeebe7e39a5ac7539f0fc146fa3c99
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you give your key a name `data`? Don't you think that this is unnecessarily confusing?

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
openssl ec -in data.pem -pubout -out pubkey.pem
```

Answer (score -1):

You can take the last 65 bytes of your private key you got from

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -out data.pem
openssl ec -in data.pem -outform DER
```

That's your public key too.

Comment: And your private key as well. Imagine sending that to somebody. OK, you described taking 65 bytes, which is only valid for the specific curve size (never mentioned) and your code doesn't actually implement it either. The result is *just* the public key point, which would not be accepted by a majority of implementations, and is missing the parameters.