# How to convert ECDSA private key to ASCII Armored key?

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl, pgp, ecdsa

I need to generate an ASCII Armored Key(as we have in PGP) from ECDSA private key.
I'm using OpenSSL to generate the ECDSA private key.

**ref:**
[Convert ECDSA private hex key to public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086121/convert-ecdsa-private-hex-key-to-public-key)

Currently I'm using the OpenPGP node module for encryption/decryption using PGP ASCII Armored keys.I want to implement above functionality using Node.js

Comment: Why don't you just create a PEM private key if you're just using `openssl`? Why cannot you just use OpenSSL command line for this? What have you tried?

Comment: I need to create a code to convert a given private key  into ASCII armored key.